# What is the exact value of this : $5\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-x^2 \text{erf}(x))x^{\sin x+\frac12}dx$?

Tags: integration, computational-mathematics, pi, wolfram-alpha

My curiousity is to get more integrals about the constant $\pi$ using special functions. I have used some special functions as shown below in the integral:

$$5\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(-x^2 \text{erf}(x)\right)x^{\sin x+\frac12}dx$$

[Wolfram alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28+5exp%28-x%C2%B2+erf%28x%29%29+x%5E%28sinx%2B0.5%29%29%2C+x%3D0+to+infty) shows the value of that integral is a rational number; however all used function are far to contribute rational values. Now my question: Does   $5\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-x^2 \text{erf}(x))x^{\sin x+\frac12}dx$ really result in a rational number? And does it close to $\pi$ if it is?

**Note:** It is very hard to compute that integral in closed form, since it has used some complicated special functions.

Comment: Why do you think the WA gives a rational result? IMO $3.14247\dots$ is a decimal approximation for the integral.

Comment: That is not IMO , it is my own problem

Comment: IMO means  _In my opinion_ (I guess you associate something other)

Comment: I do not believe you may prove that a random integral *is a rational number* from a numerical approximation.

Answer (score 1):

There's no indication that this integral evaluates to a rational number. There seems to be a bug in the mobile version of Wolfram|Alpha that you link to, in that it omits the ellipsis at the end of the approximation upon timing out. If you enter the integral in [the desktop version of the site](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral(%205exp(-x%C2%B2%20erf(x))%20x%5E(sinx%2B0.5))%2C%20x%3D0%20to%20infty), it times out with an ellipsis at the end of the approximation. It also has a “More digits” button that the mobile version lacks.

Comment: do not forget that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-x^2 \text{erf}(x))$ is constant for $x \geq 3$

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: I don't know what that means. It's an integral without an integration variable. The only variable that occurs in it is $x$, so it appears you forgot the $\mathrm dx$ (as you did in the question). But then I don't know what it might mean to say that the integral is constant for $x\ge3$, since $x$ is then a bound variable inside the integral.

Comment: @Thanks i have edited it , just a wrong typo , that's give constant from 3 to infty and it's value closed to 0.972107

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at. Every definite integral has a constant value. I don't see anything special here for $x\ge3$, nor anything related to the question whether the integral has a rational value.

Comment: if it is not rational how we can disproof that ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: We probably can't. (At least I probably can't.) It's usually difficult to prove that a number is irrational. I didn't claim that it's irrational, I just argued against your assertion that there's any indication from the Wolfram|Alpha output that it's rational.